# What is a memory image in *nix systems?

Tags: linux, unix, process, operating-system, signals

In the book *Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment 3rd Edition*, Chapter 10 -- Signals, Page 315, when talking about the actions taken by the processes that receive a signal , the author says

> When the default action is labeled "terminate+core", it means that a memory image of the process is left in the file named **core** of the current working directory of the process.

What is a memory image? When is this created, what's the content of it, and what is it used for?

Comment: A memory image is not created. It is simply the view of the current state of the systems memory at a certain time, for example when a process is killed. So basically the content of the memory. The phrase describes the action of "capturing the current memory content" in something like an image (like a photocopy) to be able to examine it afterwards.

Comment: It's used for diagnosing the reason why the program crashed.

Comment: So a memory image can be thought as a collection of information about some process?

Answer (score 3):

A memory image is simply a copy of the process's virtual memory, saved in a file. It's used when debugging the program, as you can examine the values of the program's variables and determine which functions were being called at the time of the failure.

As the documentation you quoted says, this file is created when the process is terminated due to a signal that has the "terminate+core" default action.'

Comment: So is it created and expanded automatically as a process runs?

Comment: No, it's created when the process crashes.

Answer (score 2):

A memory image is often called a core image. See [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) and the [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) wikipage.

Grossly speaking, a core image describes the process [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (and content) at time of crash (including [call stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) of each active thread and writable data segments for global data and heaps, but often excluding text or [code segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) which are read-only and given in the executable [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file or in shared libraries). It also contains the [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) state (for each thread).

The name `core` is understandable only by old guys like me (having seen computers built in the 1960 & 1970-s like [IBM/360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360), [PDP-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-10) and *early* [PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11), both used for developing the [primordial Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Unix)), since long time ago (1950-1970) random access memory was made with [magnetic ***core* memory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic-core_memory).

If you have compiled all your source code with debug information (e.g. using `gcc -g -Wall`) you can do some post-mortem [debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) (after `yourprogram`  crashed and dumped a `core` file!) using [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) as

```
gdb yourprogram core
```

and the first `gdb` command you'll try is probably `bt` to get the backtrace.

Don't forget to enable core dumps, with the [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall generally done in your shell with e.g. `ulimit  -c`

Several signals can dump core, see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). A common cause is a [segmentation violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), like when you dereference a `NULL` or bad pointer, which gives a `SIGSEGV` signal which (often) dumps a `core` file in the current directory.

See also [gcore(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html).